# WP CiviCRM shortcodes gone?

Tags: wordpress

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.18 in WordPress 4.7.4. For some time, the shortcode button has been gone. Even after re-installing CiviCRM/deactivating all other plugins I can't get it to show anymore. Has that feature been removed? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this plugin too by any chance: https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/

If so, there are settings for what post type the shortcode should appear on.

Comment: Amazing, now I am a step closer to getting to the problem's core, thank you so much! It still does not work for custom post types though, as they are not taken into account by the Admin Utilities. I will see if I can edit those...

Comment: @Julian CiviCRM Admin Utilities lists all public Post Types which have an Admin UI and which support an 'editor'. These are the basic requirements for a CiviCRM shortcode to make any sense. Check your post types and make sure they meet these requirements.